# Why is the red circle appearing in an empty review queue even with Approve Wiki Edits privilege?

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I am not sure why the red circle is appearing. The queue is ostensibly cleared but I have [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). At first I thought the ghost items triggering the circle were tag wiki edits I could not yet approve, but I just approved 3 now and now the queue is showing as cleared. I also have no pending tag wiki edits of my own. What is happening?

[image]

Comment: Kinda feels like https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ to me.

Comment: My guess would be that since you've done some reviews in this queue, "and now the queue is showing as cleared," it means there are no items left for you to review, but the number of items pending in the queue (two reviews required for the Edit queue) is still high enough to trigger the dreaded red dot.

Comment: Rydwolf has a program to automatically open review tasks in a new tab as soon as their available. People with this script (myself included) might be yoinking tasks out from under you.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Can I have that script?

Comment: The source is [here](https://github.com/Radvylf/userscripts/blob/main/generic-review-tool.user.js), though you'll need a userscript manager like Greasemonkey (Firefox) or Tampermonkey (Chrome). It also relies on the fact that you have at least one tab open to https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/review at all times.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to the fact that my reviews did not complete the tasks, since one more vote from someone else is needed to complete them. As such, there were no tasks I could review but still tasks in the queue.

This is demonstrated by the red circle disappearing as soon as another user reviewed the edits.

Comment: Essentially, the queue indicators only indicate queue content, not *your* actionable queue content. Running that query to see what you can review on every page load would be really expensive, so we don't do it. I know it can be frustrating but... :(